# How to setup background image or colour with width and height for svg element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvas, svg

I have multiple svg element and have to save it as svg format file in php or in JavaScript I have tried to save the svg element into canvas and position the text element top and left to save it as svg format file. How to save it svg element with white background and position to top left for two svg elements.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

     var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($items ); ?>;

      //console.log(jArray);
     jQuery.each(jArray,function(index, value){
 // console.log('My array has at position ' + index + ', this value: '     +       value['svg']);
   //console.log(jArray[index]['svg']);

  //console.log("value[" + index + "]);

console.log(jArray[index]['svg']);
   <svg width="248" height="109" viewBox="-2.48333740234375 0 248 109" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text>hello<text></svg>
<svg width="222" height="112" viewBox="-2.48333740234375 0 248 109" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><text>hello<text></svg>
```

Comment: `svg` and `canvas` are two different techniques of drawing. Why are you combining them?

Comment: I have to generate it as svg format to the end user with text append on it. i have tried to convert png to svg but get distorted

Comment: If your input is `svg`, and your output is `svg`, you don't need a canvas. Just modify the `svg` directly. `svg` is `xml` so it's all text.

Comment: ok how to set background image for svg with div position cho '<div style="background-color:#fff;width:333.333px;height:500px;" id="svg_elemnt">'; 
          echo '<div style="position:absolute;top:'.$top.';left:'.$left.'">';

Comment: You're not making any sense. You mention a background image but there is no image (only a colour). Also your output looks like HTML, not SVG (`div` does not exist in SVG).